Cypress e2e.js file giving error while connecting SQL server using Cucumber
I am not able connect DB connection using Cypress. Facing issue e2e.js by giving loadDBCommand.
DBConnection.feature
Scenanrio: Connect DB using SQL Server
Given Update the Agent Details
Package.json
npx cypress run --spec cypress/integrtation/bddtest/welcome.feature
e2e.js
import sqlServer from 'cypress-sql-server'; sqlServer.loadDBCommands()
Step Definition:
cy.SqlServer("Update Agent set Agent_Name='Antony' where Agent id=123")
cypress.config.js
`config.db = {
    userName: "username",
    password: "bbbbbbb!10",
    server: "Server",
    options: {
        database: "DatabaseName",
        encrypt: true,
        rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion : true
    }
}
  tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.db);
  on('task', tasks);`

I am getting error in the cypress log when I run npx cypress run --spec cypress/integrtation/bddtest/welcome.feature
If I run using Cypress Runner same query simple .js file it is working fine. ONLY I am facing issue while Running Cucumber. Kindly provide solution.
[ERRO] Could no resolve "crypto"
node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js
5| const crypto = require('crypto')
The package "crypto" was not found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: node to do that which will remove this error.
Thank you

Please do not tag-spam.

Hi I am facing issue could you please help me to fix it. Looks i am seeing many people facing similar issue. Again I am explaining code is working fine when I run through cypress test runner using simple .js file. Issue I am getting while I run through cucumber scenario. Kindly help me. Apology me I am not tag spam.
